# Is it possible to have a static function and member function of the same name in a coffeescript class?

Tags: javascript, class, static, coffeescript

If I'm phrasing the question incorrectly or it's hard to understand what I'm asking, here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```
class Number
  constructor: (@num) ->

  @add: (operand1, operand2) ->
    return operand1 + operand2

  add: (operand) =>
    @num = @add(@num, operand)

Number num1
Number num2
Number.add(num1, num2)
num1.add(num2)
```

The purpose of this would be so that `Number.add(num1, num2)` could be used statically to return the sum of two objects of the Number class and so that an object of class Number could use `num1.add(num2)` to add another number object to it using the code of the static function. When I tried to implement a similar bit of code in my project, what resulted was a recursive mess. I realized that calling @add in the add function was calling itself, which is not what is wanted here. Is what I'm trying to do even possible or am I attempting something stupid here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num1` and `num2` are objects and you must work on their `num` property:

```
class Number
  constructor: (@num) ->

  @add: (operand1, operand2) ->
    # the addition must be done on num property
    operand1.num + operand2.num

  add: (operand) ->
    # here, you must call Number.add
    Number.add(@, operand)

# to create Number, use new Number
num1 = new Number 10
num2 = new Number 5
console.log Number.add(num1, num2)
console.log num1.add(num2)
```

In both add() functions, you should check if the operands are `Number`s to avoid any errors.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you have any idea why calling apply() on the static add function is saying "cannot read property 'apply' of undefined." I'm calling it like so: `Number.add.apply(this, args)`. Doing it how I was before had the recursive problem but I was able to call apply().

Comment: I can use `apply()` inside the `add(operand)` function like this `Number.add.apply(null, [@, operand])`.

Comment: Weird. That doesn't work for me either. The function is defined if just Number.add() is called but using apply() on it complains that it isn't.

Comment: Weird, what environment are you using? I tried on http://coffeescript.org/ and with my local nodejs 5.1.0, it works on both.